# why do I get an email after my question has been answered?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, email-notification

I've seen this pretty often and this time I can confirm it and rule it as a possible small bug or maybe a future improvement.

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662440/what-is-the-equivalent-of-form-isvalid-in-winforms). I asked it on 1/11/11 and I received an answer a few minutes later, which I then marked as accepted. on 1/12/11 at 11 PM EST (~36 hours later) I get an email from Stack Overflow letting me know that I have one answer for the question.

I know I did, that's why I marked it as accepted, hence it shouldn't have sent me the email as it doesn't make sense: there is nothing new to report. Why can't we be green and save a few bytes here and there.

Maybe the logic should be to only send an email if there is new activity since I last viewed the question. Or maybe use my last activity on that answer to know if I already read it: a comment to an answer, an up/down vote, marking an answer accepted, or the last time I viewed the question.

Just my 2 cents to make SO an the SE network even better than what it currently is.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because when you post your question, in the end, there is an checkbox option saying "Notify daily of any new answers". If that is checked, you get an email notification. Make sure you uncheck that option to save the bytes.

Comment: That's my whole point. Only notify if it is truly a new answer that I haven't read.

Answer (score 1):

We now send email for the inbox as a whole (rather than each site and question) **and only for items (if any) that you haven't read yet**.  The behavior you're after for email notifications that only tell you something is in place, in a very different way.